# My xpath evaluator and my code seem to be getting different results

Tags: c#, xpath, xpathnavigator

**Ignore this question please.  The problem was with data coming into the method and not with any of the code/xml I wrote in the question.  I would delete the question but it already has answers.**

I have some XML which I tested a XPath query against an evaluator and got the expected results, but my code cannot seem reach the same results.

Here is a fragment of the XML

```
<custom-table security="seeown" allownotify="false">
  <reports show="all">
    <report aspurl="../Reports/" label="Buy Sheet" security="moderator"/>
  </reports>
  <select-field name="StatusQ3MAP" eval="false">
    <option value="Accept" label="Accept"/>
    <option value="Decline" label="Decline"/>
  </select-field>
  <select-field name="MerchantStatus" eval="false">
    <option value="Review 1" label="Review 1"/>
    <option value="Review 2" label="Review 2"/>
  </select-field>
</custom-table>
```

My XPath looks like `custom-table/select-field[@name="StatusQ3MAP"]` which gets me the appropriate select-field element in the XML.

However, my method which is not appearing to work is:

```
public static List<string> GetListItems(string fieldName, XPathNavigator nav)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    var nodes = nav.Select(string.Format("/custom-table/select-field[@name = '{0}']", fieldName));

    foreach (XPathNavigator item in nodes)
        list.Add(item.Value);

    return list;
}
```

Assuming fieldName is "StatusQ3MAP" there appear to be nothing in nodes and thus getting no results back in the list.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `string.Format("/custom-table/select-field[@name = '{0}']", fieldName)` to just `custom-table/select-field[@name = '"+fieldName+"']"`

Comment: @JWiley, I tried this just now and got the same result.

Comment: @JWiley, also, to remove any ambiguity from that aspect I tried hardcoding the xpath query exactly like my example in my question and it still failed.

Answer (score 0):

The `XPathNavigator.Select` expects a `XPathExpression`. Change your code to

```
XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile(string.Format("custom-table/select-field[@name= '{0}']",fieldName));
XPathNodeIterator iter = nav.Select(expr);
while(iter.MoveNext())
{
  list.Add(iter.Current);
}
```

Comment: Intellisense says I can do a xpath string but I tried your idea out anyway and it did not work. Same result.

Comment: Please try with my edit, and yeah you were correct, it will work with string also

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XPathNodeIterator nodes = nav.Select(string.Format("/custom-table/select-field[@name = '{0}']", fieldName));

foreach (XPathIterator item in nodes)
        list.Add(item.Value);
```

Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k4x060d.aspx), it may clear something up for you.

Comment: I changed the type to `var` and changed made the line read `list.Add(item.ToString())` just to see what would happen. The nodes does not appear to have anything to iterate over, list.Add is never hit.  I'm guessing there must be an issue with my XPathNavigator I'm passing in.